# system_clock and ctime leading to uninitialized value memory errors in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm writing a utility function to get the current hour from the system clock. I've included  and other necessary libraries; my code compiles completely and runs.

When I run valgrind, I'm getting errors that say "uninitialized value was created by a stack allocation" and corresponding "conditional jump depends on uninitialized value(s)" errors. I've narrowed it down to the following function:

```
size_t get_hour(){
    chrono::duration<int,ratio<60*60*24>> one_day (1);
    chrono::system_clock::time_point today = chrono::system_clock::now();
    time_t tt = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t (today);
    const char hr[2] = {ctime(&tt)[11], ctime(&tt)[12]};
    return (size_t)stoi(hr);
}
```

which is functioning correctly (i.e. returning the correct time as a two digit number). Yet, these memory errors make me think I'm doing something wrong by assigning `ctime(&tt)[11]` and `ctime(&tt)[12]` to my `const char hr[2]`

My first guess was that, if the current hour is a single digit, either the 11th or 12th indices are undefined from the `ctime` call - but I played around with printing these values at various times and they all seem to be printing correctly. What's more, I'm getting these errors regardless of the time of day.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I haven't been able to find many relevant examples of using ctime and system_clock correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: `hr` is not null-terminated.

Comment: To be a C-style string `hr` would have to have a third byte containing `'\0'`.

Comment: @BoPersson Thank you - that was it! Not the first time I've forgotten to null-terminate a c-string when mixing C and C++...